# Problema al descomentar ";" Curl en php.ini instalando magento 2

Tags: magento2

En la instalación de Magento 2 tengo este issue:

PHP Extensions Check
1 missing PHP extensions.

PHP Extension curl.

y ya he descomentado en el php.ini:

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll    
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

y aún así me sigue saliendo el error ..

Comment: para magento tienes instalado algo como wampserver o xampp?

Comment: Si un servidor local sobre windows 10: se llama EasyPHP

Comment: A veces es diferente el php ini que se usa para el servidor local que el que se usa para el php, puede que tú hayas modificado el del php pero el del servidor sigue igual, busca si por ahí no hay otro php.ini

Comment: dentro de apache hay un php.ini, pero allí también está descomentado curl.

Comment: después de descomentar reiniciaste el servidor web? si no reinicia el servidor web.

Comment: Sería mejor usar una máquina virtual o docker, para evitar todo este tipo de inconvenientes con esos paquetes estilo wamp / Easyphp que pueden tener muchos problemas de dependencias e incompatibilidades con los sistemas operativos y otros factores externos.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, Si reinicie el servidor después de descomentar la librería... Ok cual máquina virtual me recomendás? virtual box?